# Regexpression - replace quoted string with begin and end quotes

Tags: java, regex

I have an arbitray string, e.g.

```
String multiline=`
This is my "test" case
with lines
\section{new section}
Another incorrect test"
\section{next section}
With some more "text"
`
```

I use LaTeX and I want to replace the quotes with those which are used in books - similar to ,, and ´´ For this I need to replace the beginning quotes with a `\glqq` and the ending with a `\qrqq`. Since I'm not pretty sure if the quotes are done properly in the text I don't want to have them continued forever. i.e. after each `\section{...}` a new replace mechanism should start.

I am coding the whole stuff in Java. Therefore I thought I first split the string into various pieces of section, e.g. `.split('^\\section\{[.*$')` how to replace the beginning and the ending quotes differently? Is this 'easy' possible within a closed regular expression or should I do it by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sample:

```java
String line = "This is my \"test\" case with some more \"text\"";
line = line.replaceAll("\"([\\w]+)\"", "\u00AB$1\u00BB");
System.out.println(line);
```

Output:

```
This is my «test» case with some more «text»
```